# What is purpose of backup-power-connectors on 826701-B21 (Riser Card)?

Tags: hardware, hp, pci-express, hpe

What is the purpose of the connectors marked with 2 on the HP DL380's Riser card?

[image: 826701-B21 HP-DL380 Gen10 Riser-Card]

Is it something for backing up power shocks on the PCI controller connected to the port?
and if it is, then where I can find the cables/card/battery that can be connected there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those appear to be power connectors for RAID cards. If you put a storage controller on that riser that requires backup power, those ports on the riser are where you would plug them in.

[Here's a section](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00019109en_us&docLocale=en_US&page=GUID-8351A7F6-12EF-4863-A5BE-2EACBB415AC8.html) of the user manual that shows how you would use this. It refers to a section called "riser board components" which looks like the page you snipped that graphic from. (Hint - in the future, include links to resources like that.)

> **Cable routing: Smart Array P824i-P Controller**
>
> **Backup power cable**
>
> A smart storage battery is required with this controller. Your riser
> might look different from the one shown. To locate a backup power
> connector, see "Riser board components".

Comment: just for clarification, that means the battery connected like is shown in the [link](https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/iss/DL380_Gen10/setup_install/229655.png) can provide an energy buffer to the RAID cards? 
or do I need a different battery?

Comment: You've really got to read the actual manual. "A smart storage battery is required with this controller" is from the link in my answer. In that same document, you can search for "smart storage battery" and find this page - https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00019109en_us&docLocale=en_US&page=GUID-D921369A-74D7-4ABF-9DEE-42F5C887D2B8.html  .  The riser card isn't really the point; you need a storage card that can work with that battery. Some RAID cards come with a battery already on the card.